# In jquery how can I check a checkbox by its text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="2">Access</input>
```

Is there a way to check the checkbox based on the input´s text?
something like

```
Access.prop('checked', true);
```

I dont need to se if its checked I need to change it to checked

Comment: `<input>` isn't a container element, it doesn't have any text.

Comment: `</input>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: What is `Access`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery This might be help you in the right direction

Comment: Access is the text in the input

Comment: `.prop()` is a jQuery function, it has to be applied to a jQuery object, not a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input>` elements don't have any text, because they're not containers. You can wrap it in a DIV or some other container element, and then search for that DIV by its contents with `:contains`.

```js
$(":checkbox").parent(":contains(Access)").children(":checkbox").prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="2">Access</div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="permission[]" value="2">Something else</div>
```

Comment: @AhmetCanGüven I long ago stopped worrying about why people give me downvotes on good answers.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote cant control that but thanks you were really helpful

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element). You can use `<label>` element, `for` attribute.

To check `<label>` element `.htmlFor` elements use `.control.checked =`"checked"`

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="permission" name="permission[]" value="2">
<label for="permission">Access</label>
<script>
document.querySelector("[for=permission]").control.checked = "checked";
</script>
```

Comment: How does he use this in the Javascript to check the box based on the label containing `Access`?

Comment: @Barmar Click the `<label>` element at `html`.

Comment: He wants to use Javascript to check it.

Comment: @guest271314 it is still not related with the question. He wanted to check based on the text when document is ready.

Comment: he wants to find the checkbox based on the text "Access" in the label. If you're going to hard-code the ID of the checkbox, what's the point of going through the label?

Comment: You might as well just write `document.querySelector("#permission").checked = "checked"`

Comment: @Barmar The actual Question is _"In jquery how can I check a checkbox by its text"_ . Given that `<input>` elements do not have text, the `<label>` element is used for `<input>` text in `form`, or anywhere in `document`. Provided `<label>` element to meet requirement, as that  is one use of `<label>` element. Then set `.checked` at `.control` element using `label` element. How does this not meet requirement of actual Question?

Comment: The input to whatever he's doing is the string "Access". He wants to find the checkbox whose label contains that string, without knowing its ID.

Comment: @Barmar Did not interpret Question the same way, here. Though that is ok. `<label>` elements can be used for that specific purpose. No need to query string in `document`; instead use `<label>` element to reference `.control`, where the text within label can be anything, or nothing.

Comment: What do you think he means by "based on the input´s text"? He wants to find the string "Access", then check the checkbox next to it. If he knew the ID of the checkbox, he wouldn't need to search for it based on the text.

Comment: @Barmar _"What do you think he means by "based on the input´s text"?"_ Given `<input>` element is empty element, where the input does not contain "input's text", that `<label>` element would be appropriate option to achieve expected result, as the element can be used for that specific purpose. Even your Answer does not get or set based on "input's text".

Comment: Yes, the label is appropriate. But you still have to search for the label by its text, not by its `for=` attribute.

Comment: You should find the label that contains `Access`, then use `document.getElementById(label.for).checked = 'checked';`

Comment: Why would you search by text? Text can be anything. Use the direct linkage  feature of `.control`. Ok, can do that as well. Though would probably suggest using `data-*` attribute having value `"Access"`. Not sure if the effective result would be different from using approach at present Answer?